# I'd like to fill up the color of the square using GDI

Tags: c#, winforms, gdi+

[image]

**I made a square of 18*18 now. I'd like to fill the first boundary of the square with black color like in the picture,**

what should I do?

```
  public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private int XTILES = 25;
    private int YTILES = 25;
    private int TILELOCATION = 20;
    Graphics g;
    Pen pen;
 
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        pen = new Pen(Color.Black);        
    }

    private void DrawBoard()
    {
        g = panel.CreateGraphics();
        for(int i = 0; i < 19; i++)
        {
            g.DrawLine(pen, new Point(TILELOCATION + i * XTILES, TILELOCATION),
                new Point(TILELOCATION + i * XTILES, TILELOCATION + 18 * XTILES));

            g.DrawLine(pen, new Point(TILELOCATION, TILELOCATION + i * YTILES),
               new Point(TILELOCATION + 18 * YTILES, TILELOCATION + i * YTILES));
        }
    }
    private void panel_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);
        DrawBoard();
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all, stop calling `CreateGraphics`. You're already doing your drawing on the `Paint` event, so that's good, but you should be using the `Graphics` object provided by that event, i.e. `e.Graphics` in the event handler. Change your `DrawBoard` method and add a `Graphics` parameter and use that instead of creating one, then pass `e.Graphics` as an argument when calling it.

Comment: As for the question, there are various ways this could be handled. My first thought is that, if you have an 18x18 board, create a 18x18 2D array of `Rectangles`. You can then call `Graphics.FillRectangle` when and where appropriate and pass the appropriate `Rectangle` from the array. Drawing your border would mean calling `FillRectangle` for each element with either index of 0 or 17.

Comment: ...And, of course, you don't call `base.OnPaint(e);` in the Paint event handler. Also, note that you're calling the `OnPaint()` method of the Form here, which doesn't make any sense. You call `base.OnPaint(e);` in the `OnPaint()` override of a Control

Comment: I'm still very clumsy because I'm a beginner at GDI. Thank you.

Comment: Note that DrawRectangle's width/height params are off by one!

Comment: Is the grid a `TableLayoutPanel` or is it a custom control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways. Here is one of them: Draw top, left, right and bottom edges separately using FillRect.

```
    Brush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);

    private void panel_Paint(object? sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        DrawBoundary(e.Graphics);
    }

    void DrawBoundary(Graphics g)
    {
        g.FillRectangle(brush, ToGraphics(new Rectangle(0, 0, XTILES, 1)));
        g.FillRectangle(brush, ToGraphics(new Rectangle(XTILES - 1, 0, 1, YTILES)));
        g.FillRectangle(brush, ToGraphics(new Rectangle(0, YTILES - 1, XTILES, 1)));
        g.FillRectangle(brush, ToGraphics(new Rectangle(0, 0, 1, YTILES - 1)));
    }

    public Rectangle ToGraphics(Rectangle r)
    {
        return new Rectangle(TILELOCATION + r.X * TILESIZE, TILELOCATION + r.Y * TILESIZE, r.Width * TILESIZE, r.Height * TILESIZE);
    }
```

[ADDED- see comments]:

```
    void DrawBoard(Graphics g)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= XTILES; i++)
            g.DrawLine(pen, 
                new Point(TILELOCATION + i * TILESIZE, TILELOCATION),
                new Point(TILELOCATION + i * TILESIZE, TILELOCATION + YTILES * TILESIZE - 1));

        for (int i = 0; i <= YTILES; i++)
            g.DrawLine(pen, 
                new Point(TILELOCATION, TILELOCATION + i * TILESIZE),
                new Point(TILELOCATION + XTILES * TILESIZE - 1, TILELOCATION + i * TILESIZE));
    }
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer.
But there is a problem with your answer.
If TILESIZE is set to 18, the boundary is filled, but there is a problem that there is a slight margin. How do we solve this?

Comment: I would say the problem is in DrawBoard(), where you're using XTILES and YTILES instead of TILESIZE for calculating line positions. Also, you should not use hard-wired numbers 18 and 19 in this method, but XTILES and YTILES. I'll add fixed DrawBoard method to the answer.

Comment: Also note that if you draw a line using DrawLine() from point [0,0] to [10, 0], then 11 pixels are drawn, while if you fill a rect by FillRect defined by XY:[0,0] and WH:[10,10], then only 10 pixels (in both directions) are filled. That's why I decrement the right and bottom coordinates by 1 in DrawBoard(). Otherwise, the lines would exceed the border. You may decide to solve this issue by another way.